# Text responsive with the d3.js treemap tiles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I am working with the d3.js treemap layout . In the tiles the font size is too small . How to display in a bigger font for big tiles and smaller for small tiles or display the label text at the center of each tiles. Find my code link here https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mccarthy-wfbtg. The label can be centered and the font size can be increased for better view. Also the title contains the total which I dont want to show how to remove the count in the breadcrumb title alone.
[image]

Logic is here

```
createTreeChart = () => {
    const width = 550;
    const height = 600;
    const padding = 60;
    const format = d3.format(",d");
    const name = d =>
      d
        .ancestors()
        .reverse()
        .map(d => d.data.name)
        .join("/");
    function tile(node, x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      d3.treemapBinary(node, 0, 0, width, height);
      for (const child of node.children) {
        child.x0 = x0 + (child.x0 / width) * (x1 - x0);
        child.x1 = x0 + (child.x1 / width) * (x1 - x0);
        child.y0 = y0 + (child.y0 / height) * (y1 - y0);
        child.y1 = y0 + (child.y1 / height) * (y1 - y0);
      }
    }
    const treemap = data =>
      d3.treemap().tile(tile)(
        d3
          .hierarchy(data)
          .sum(d => d.value)
          .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value)
      );
    const svg = d3
      .select("#chart")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

    const x = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, width]);
    const y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([0, height]);

    // const svg = d3
    //   .create("svg")
    //   .select("#chart")
    //   .append("svg")
    //   .attr("viewBox", [0.5, -30.5, width, height + 30])
    //   .style("font", "10px sans-serif");

    let group = svg.append("g").call(render, treemap(data));

    function render(group, root) {
      const node = group
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(root.children.concat(root))
        .join("g");

      node
        .filter(d => (d === root ? d.parent : d.children))
        .attr("cursor", "pointer")
        .on("click", d => (d === root ? zoomout(root) : zoomin(d)));

      node.append("title").text(d => `${name(d)}\n${format(d.value)}`);

      node
        .append("rect")
        .attr("id", d => (d.leafUid = "leaf"))
        .attr("fill", d => (d === root ? "#fff" : d.children ? "#ccc" : "#ddd"))
        .attr("stroke", "#fff");

      node
        .append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", d => (d.clipUid = "clip"))
        .append("use")
        .attr("xlink:href", d => d.leafUid.href);

      node
        .append("text")
        .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
        .attr("font-weight", d => (d === root ? "bold" : null))
        .selectAll("tspan")
        .data(d =>
          (d === root ? name(d) : d.data.name)
            .split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g)
            .concat(format(d.value))
        )
        .join("tspan")
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr(
          "y",
          (d, i, nodes) => `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + 1.1 + i * 0.9}em`
        )
        .attr("fill-opacity", (d, i, nodes) =>
          i === nodes.length - 1 ? 0.7 : null
        )
        .attr("font-weight", (d, i, nodes) =>
          i === nodes.length - 1 ? "normal" : null
        )
        .text(d => d);

      group.call(position, root);
    }

    function position(group, root) {
      group
        .selectAll("g")
        .attr("transform", d =>
          d === root ? `translate(0,-30)` : `translate(${x(d.x0)},${y(d.y0)})`
        )
        .select("rect")
        .attr("width", d => (d === root ? width : x(d.x1) - x(d.x0)))
        .attr("height", d => (d === root ? 30 : y(d.y1) - y(d.y0)));
    }

    // When zooming in, draw the new nodes on top, and fade them in.
    function zoomin(d) {
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.append("g").call(render, d));

      x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
      y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);

      svg
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t =>
          group0
            .transition(t)
            .remove()
            .call(position, d.parent)
        )
        .call(t =>
          group1
            .transition(t)
            .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(0, 1))
            .call(position, d)
        );
    }

    // When zooming out, draw the old nodes on top, and fade them out.
    function zoomout(d) {
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent));

      x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
      y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);

      svg
        .transition()
        .duration(750)
        .call(t =>
          group0
            .transition(t)
            .remove()
            .attrTween("opacity", () => d3.interpolate(1, 0))
            .call(position, d)
        )
        .call(t => group1.transition(t).call(position, d.parent));
    }

    return svg.node();
  };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `font-size` attribute of the text nodes. Add `.attr("font-size", ...)` as the following.

```js
node
    .append("text")
    .attr("clip-path", d => d.clipUid)
    .attr("font-weight", d => (d === root ? "bold" : null))
    .attr("font-size", d => {
          if (d === root) return "1em";
          const width = x(d.x1) - x(d.x0), height = y(d.y1) - y(d.y0);
          return Math.max(Math.min(width/5, height/2, Math.sqrt((width*width + height*height))/10), 9)
        })
    .selectAll("tspan")
    ...
```

This sets the `font-size` to 10% of the diagonal of each rect.
In case the text becomes too small to read, `font-size` is set to the minimum of 9. The texts might become too big for rects that are vertically long, so the maximum set to one fifth of the width of the rect or half of the height of the rect, whichever is bigger.

The font-size doesn't scale correctly after zooming because `x` and `y` scales' domains are updated only after `render`. Update the domains before calling `render` in `zoomin` and `zoomout` functions.

```js
function zoomin(d) {
      x.domain([d.x0, d.x1]);
      y.domain([d.y0, d.y1]);
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.append("g").call(render, d));
      ...
    }

function zoomout(d) {
      x.domain([d.parent.x0, d.parent.x1]);
      y.domain([d.parent.y0, d.parent.y1]);
      const group0 = group.attr("pointer-events", "none");
      const group1 = (group = svg.insert("g", "*").call(render, d.parent));
      ...
    }
```

**Breadcrumb fix**. When you set the rectangles' `tspan`s' `x` and `y`, you are also setting the `x` and `y` of the `tspan`s in the breadcrumb with the same logic. The easiest way to solve this is simply to make the breadcrumb one `tspan`. This, however, limits the styling of the breadcrumb. Instead, style the breadcrumb text separately at the end of the render function.

```js
...
        .text(d => d);

      node.selectAll('text').filter(d => d === root)
        .selectAll("tspan").attr("y", '1.1em').attr("x", undefined);

      group.call(position, root);
```

And the regex for the breadcrumb text doesn't look like it's working out. It's separating the text at odd places. Change `name(d).split(/(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])/g)` to `name(d).split(/(?=\/)/g)`.

Text centering. There's a lot to be done. Text anchor is set to middle, and `transform: translate` text boxes by half of width/height.

```
        .attr("text-anchor", d => d === root ? null : "middle")
        .attr("transform", d=> d === root ? null : 
          `translate(${(x(d.x1) - x(d.x0))/2}, ${(y(d.y1) - y(d.y0))/2})`)
        .selectAll("tspan")
```

And change `tspan`s' `y` to center them vertically.

```
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr(
          "y",
          (d, i, nodes) => `${(i === nodes.length - 1) * 0.3 + (i - nodes.length/2) * 0.9}em`
        )
```

Comment: Thanks @Hurried-Helpful , but when I drill down to a segment the font is same as its parent and when I go back the font sizes got increased for each parent level label text and is not consistent

Comment: I don't really get what you are saying. Can you explain what needs fixing?

Comment: check this https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mccarthy-wfbtg. For the first level it is perfect. One level down children the text is not having dynamic font size. And also when you go back one level up all the fonts are very big.

Comment: I see what you mean. I updated the answer. I never bothered to click the rects before. My bad.

Comment: That's really helpful can I ask you another question. As you can see the treemap in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mccarthy-wfbtg when you drilldown to a child the title breadcrumb overlapping with the segments rect. How can I stop that ?

Comment: Fixed it. `x` and `y` of the breadcrumb's `tspan`s are now separately styled.

Comment: Great work! You are too good in d3. Another question from me. How to center the label text at the center of each tiles ?

Comment: And they are centered.

Comment: l have changed the input datas. Now in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mccarthy-wfbtg , some text are getting overlapped. Can you help me out ?